# Cost of Explicit Q in Householder QR Factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I know that the cost of Householder QR is $2n^2(m-n/3)$ flops, without finding $Q$ explicitly. However, it was mentioned in lecture that computing $Q$ explicitly raises the cost to $4(m^2n +n^3/3- mn^2  )$.

I'm not sure how though. (Every time I try, I get an $O(nm^3)$ term somehow). Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess you want to multiply all the Householder reflections. They are quite special (identity + rank 1 update) and can be multiplied much more efficiently than using the "naive" matrix-matrix multiplication (note that $(xx^T)y=x(x^Ty)$ on a paper but one has quadratic and the other linear complexity in terms of the vector sizes).

Comment: May I ask what lecture you refer to?

Comment: @TA123 From a course on matrix computation theory. Unfortunately, the notes/lectures are not online.